# Optimal load balancing of unequal tasks and progress bars in R

Tags: r, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, load-balancing

I have N tasks which I wish to parallelize across M cores in R. These tasks vary significantly in how long they will take to perform. Fortunately, I have a rough indication of which tasks are going to be slow and which are going to be fast. I also have a progress bar which increments by the number of tasks completed.

I want to optimise the order of the tasks such that:

1. Total computation time is minimised
2. The progress bar is representative of the time remaining, not the tasks remaining.

To give a more practical example:

```
do_task <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(x ** 2)
}

tasks <- 1:10

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
pbapply::pboptions(use_lb = TRUE)
pbapply::pblapply(tasks, do_task, cl = cl)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

The total processing time is 6 minutes and 32 seconds and the progress bar moves initially quickly but then very slowly as the tasks take longer and longer.

Or going from longest to shortest:

```
tasks <- 10:1
```

This takes 2 minutes and 20 seconds, so much faster. But the progress bar starts very slowly and then suddenly speeds up.

I also tried interleaving the tasks.

```
tasks <- c(10,1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5)
```

This takes 3 minutes and 20 seconds, not the fastest but did give a more balanced progress bar.

Comment: If your estimation of time is good, then ordering by decreasing time will always be the fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Futher research found [this](https://github.com/psolymos/pbapply/issues/34)

Which suggests that the load balancing in pbapply is poor. They give an example which I have adapted

```
pb <- utils::txtProgressBar(max = 10, style = 3)
progress <- function(n) utils::setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
opts <- list(progress = progress)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)
boot <- foreach::foreach(i = tasks, .options.snow = opts)
res_all <- foreach::`%dopar%`(boot, do_task(i))
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

This runs is 105 seconds close to the optimal time of 100 seconds and much better than any other method I have found. The progress bar is still highly uneven, but at least it is fast.